# 500 Internal server error Web Server Apache on Centos without error log

Tags: php, apache, centos7

I have a fresh `Centos 7` with `Apache 2.4.6` and `PHP 7.0.33`.

I try to install site in `/apps/lab/htdocs/web`. I define a virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName lab.bt.be
DocumentRoot "/apps/lab/htdocs/web"

<Directory "/apps/lab/htdocs/web">
AllowOverride All
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/0_error.log"
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/0_access.log" combined

LogFormat "%h %t \"%r\" %>s \"%f\" \"%m\" \"%p\" \"%q\" \"%O\""  myLog
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/0_myLog.log" myLog

</VirtualHost>
```

**My .htaccess file**

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

**My app.php file**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
}

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);

if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
}
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
?>
```

I hope to receive more details about the error but I only receive "the server returned a "500 Internal Server Error". No information from PHP.

In the log file, I have only a line with status code 500.

1. I change context type to "httpd_sys_content_t" at /apps, /apps/lab, /apps/lab/htdocs and all folders and files in /apps/lab/htdocs.
2. I change the permission of all files and folders in /apps/lab/htdocs to 755.
3. I check the .htaccess file syntax with http://www.htaccesscheck.com/ and it's OK
4. I rename my .htaccess and create a simple index.html. The site is ok.
5. I add following lines in file app.php, only "the server returned a "500 Internal Server Error" appears when I try the site

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

I need some help.

Comment: Is `AppKernel` under the global namespace?

Comment: @apokryfos It sounds like the .htaccess file is causing the problem. Don't know why.